# react native can not build ios app Error: RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, cocoapods

I am trying to build ios version of react native project,
android version is running.
I can not make the ios version run on mac, trying using expo, or just by simulator.
[image: expo result]
After running expo start this are the errors:

```
Error: RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS, ensure you have correctly included the RNFirebase pod in your projects `Podfile` and have run `pod install`.
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

When I run react-native run-ios I get this errors:

```
The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/agam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/leaders-dwqehxydbohqcgbabuncaztlrzsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFirebase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNFirebaseFirestore.o /Users/agam/Desktop/theleadersapp/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/firestore/RNFirebaseFirestore.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RNFirebase' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

This is my package.json

```
    {
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "postinstall": "jetify"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.9.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.9.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "1.16.1",
    "@unimodules/react-native-adapter": "~6.3.4",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "expo": "^42.0.0",
    "expo-cli": "^4.8.1",
    "expo-font": "~9.2.1",
    "hashmap": "^2.4.0",
    "i18n-js": "^3.5.1",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "pod-install": "^0.1.27",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-calendar-picker": "^6.0.5",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-dropdown": "0.0.6",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.15.0",
    "react-native-icon-badge": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-instagram-login": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-localize": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-modal-picker": "0.0.16",
    "react-native-multiple-select-list": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-picker-module": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^7.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-ui-xg": "0.0.6",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.14.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.6.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^3.0.1",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^1.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "unimodules-app-loader": "~2.2.0",
    "watchman": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "babel-jest": "~24.9.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "8.3.0",
    "jest": "~24.9.0",
    "jetifier": "~1.6.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "~0.56.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.9.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This is my pod file:

```
     platform :ios, '11.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'


target 'leaders' do
#  rnPrefix = "../node_modules/react-native"
    use_unimodules!
    config=use_native_modules!
    use_react_native!(:path=>config["reactNativePath"])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ios // from your main directory
pod install
```

also, RNFirebase is commented out in your podFile here:

```
#pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase'
```

The error is telling you that this pod is not installed and this might be why

Comment: that is not the issue, I was advised to change the pod file to:
platform :ios, '11.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'


target 'leaders' do
    use_unimodules!
    config=use_native_modules!
    use_react_native!(:path=>config["reactNativePath"])
end

Comment: @shai both RNFirebase and RNFBMessaging are commented out in your podfile, so they are never installed in pod install.